# can I display a "Show" action with a static URL (route without the id parameter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action

Is it possible to display a static url for a show action (for example something like /coming_soon and not /invitations/:id) ?

Why?

I want that after a create action the new view rendered (/coming_soon) displays the specific id of the created invitation. Can I use a get request to do this? Do I have to use a global var in my create action?

As info, here is my invitation controller:

```
  def show
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end

  def create
    @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
    if @invitation.save
      redirect_to @invitation
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to redirect the user to the "show" action of the invitations controller after a create action.
In the view of the show action (or name it coming_soon) you want to have access to the ID of the invitation which is just created in the create action.

To achieve this the easiest might be to store the ID in a cookie or session, read it out in the show action and then remove it.
When using sessions you might get problems with horizontal scaling if you need this later on.

Comment: Hi Danny, first sorry for my english:( ...  I think this is the right solution to achieve what I want. Just one thing, what is horizontal scaling?

Comment: This is if the website is visited a lot and you have more webservers to handle more users. Because sessions are stored on the server you get issues that the session data is stored on server #1 and then the user suddenly gets the next page served from server #2 which doesn't have the session data :)

Comment: Thank you. (note: if you want to see what I am exactly trying to achieve: go on usehipster.com, you have to enter your email then it redirects you to a coming_soon page with a url (which includes the id).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly then in your routes.rb you are looking for

`match '/coming_soon', :to => 'controller_name#show'`

also for more routing help check out this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is possible, so what I would like to achieve is to keep the id of my object created (with a new var in the created action), and render it in another view (for example views/invitations/show.html.Erb).

Comment: i am not 100% sure what you are asking here, so sorry if I get this wrong, but if you register your route as I mentioned you can just to redirect_to coming_soon_path and that should do what you need

Comment: err actually you would want redirect_to coming_soon_path(@invitation) and that should pass your object along for you